# Why the float block must be the front?

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div id="logo_container">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height="40" width="135">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">首页</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">文章</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">作品</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">关于</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.nav_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.nav {
    float: right;
}
#logo_container {
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 135px;
}
#logo_container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

If `div#logo_container` before the `ul`,the `ul` block will be out it father block and bellow it father's block.

I have set `div#logo_container` width,and set margin、padding to 0px;but why `ul` block still show in next line and out of the father block.

But when I put the `ul` before `div#logo_container`,it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

`.nav` will be placed under `#logo_container` because `#logo_container` is `block-level`.

```css
.nav_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.nav {
    float: right;
}
#logo_container {
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 135px;
}
#logo_container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#logo_container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div id="logo_container">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height="40" width="135">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">首页</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">文章</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">作品</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">关于</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```